# how to convert old visual c++ code (vc++ 6.0) to visual studio 2019, libc missing

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, command-line-interface, visual-studio-2019

I have some old Visual C++ (v 6.0) code that runs as a CLI application and builds with an nmake file, that I would like to convert to something I can build (in a shell window not under the IDE) in Visual Studio 2019.  It uses a library I build similarly.  My makefiles will be included at the bottom.

I found 
`c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\common7\tools\vsvars32.bat`
and with that I can run nmake as I need (I have a .bat file that builds about 30 of these programs as a kind of testbase for the tool and its library and I run it within Emacs and compare the outputs to the last time I ran it, expecting the only differences to be date time stamps, compiler versions, and the ilk.)

However, when I get to the linking stage, I get the error
`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBC.lib'`

I looked in the relevant lib directory and found lots of variants of libcxxx.lib but no plain libc.lib.  I don't know if the issue is command line arguments I have passed to CL or something else.  Hence, this question.

```
# makefile for prog (a hello world type example)
DEFINES=
INCLUDES= -I. -I.\inc.vc -I\yxx\inc.vc -I\yxx\lib.vc
CXXFLAGS= /c /Od /W3 /Za $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
CXX=cl

OBJECTS=yy_main.obj \
    yy_mylex.obj \
    yy_mypsr.obj

yy_main.obj: \yxx\lib.vc\yy_main.cpp yy_mypsr.h yy_err.tbl yy_syna.tbl
    echo $(CXXFLAGS) >$*.OPT
    $(CXX) /Fo$@ @$*.OPT \yxx\lib.vc\$*.CPP >$*.ERR
    TYPE $*.ERR

yy_mylex.obj: yy_mylex.cpp yy_mylex.h
    echo $(CXXFLAGS) >$*.OPT
    $(CXX) /Fo$@ @$*.OPT $*.CPP >$*.ERR
    TYPE $*.ERR

yy_mypsr.obj: yy_mypsr.cpp
    echo $(CXXFLAGS) >$*.OPT
    $(CXX) /Fo$@ @$*.OPT $*.CPP >$*.ERR
    TYPE $*.ERR

prog.exe: $(OBJECTS) \yxx\lib.vc\yy_lol.lib
    CL @<<
$(OBJECTS)
\yxx\lib.vc\yy_lol.lib
/link /out:prog.exe
<<


# makefile for yy_lol.lib (lists of object files pruned to be smaller)
DEFINES= -Dyy_assert_disable_
INCLUDES= -I. -I\yxx\inc.vc -I\yxx\lib.vc
ARFLAGS=
CXXFLAGS= /c /Od /W3 /Za $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
CXX=cl
AR=LIB
RM=del

OBJECTS=\yxx\lib.vc\yy_asrt.obj \
    \yxx\lib.vc\yy_ast.obj \
    \yxx\lib.vc\yy_bktrk.obj \
    \yxx\lib.vc\yy_buf.obj \
    \yxx\lib.vc\yy_sym.obj

.cpp.obj:
    echo $(CXXFLAGS) >$*.OPT
    $(CXX) /Fo$@ @$*.OPT $*.CPP >$*.ERR
    TYPE $*.ERR

yy_lol.lib: $(OBJECTS)
    -$(RM) $@
    -$(AR) /out:$@ $(ARFLAGS) \yxx\lib.vc\yy_asrt.obj
    -$(AR) $@ $(ARFLAGS) \yxx\lib.vc\yy_ast.obj
    -$(AR) $@ $(ARFLAGS) \yxx\lib.vc\yy_bktrk.obj
    -$(AR) $@ $(ARFLAGS) \yxx\lib.vc\yy_buf.obj
    -$(AR) $@ $(ARFLAGS) \yxx\lib.vc\yy_sym.obj
```

Comment: That's a big version jump! VC++6 is now over two decades old... you're likely to find lots of little issues. I cannot recall the details of what was in each different link library. I suggest not including it and see which symbols cannot be resolved, then identify which library in the VC++2019 tool chain defines that symbol.

Comment: The code all compiles fine with VC++2019 (I get some warnings about using sprintf and strcpy rather than their _s versions) and it is a "Hello World" type app so there aren't any esoteric calls in it.  I know it compiled with vc++2003 because I used that in 2005.  I also had it working in 2011 and 2015, but I don't know which visual studio I was using then.  Moreover, a much more complicated version works in visual studio 2019 with a vcxproj.  I just want a command line compilation to work, so I can code in Emacs like I do in Linux.

Comment: However, how do I disable loading LIBC.lib?  I'm not linking it explicitly, at least not as far as I know.  You can see my compile and link commands.  They are all trivial.

Comment: You may need to override defaults (there are a number of libraries that are included by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, there is no libc as such: it depends on the linkage model you are working from

- Single threaded (does not exist from VS10 onwards)
- Single threaded Debug (does not exist from VS10 onwards)
- Multi threaded
- Multi threaded Debug
- Multi threaded DLL
- Multi threaded Debug DLL

It picks up a different libc depending on which model you are using.  At a guess the libc came from the single threaded model (non-debug) that no longer exists.

For the same functionality, try using libcmt.lib - the multi-threaded non-debug version.

Comment: Thanks.  That sounds like a good hint.  Yes, the code is single threaded.  It's basically "Hello World".

Comment: Ok, I have found that if I simply include all the library files as objects in the link step, I get a working executable, so I must be doing something wrong in building the library that causes it to think it needs libc.

Comment: Check the date/time - was the library actually rebuilt?

Comment: I just rebuilt it.  If I build and use the library as a library, it breaks (needs libc.lib) and if I just link the objects in directly, it builds and runs fine.  I'm closer to my problem.

Comment: Does your library build have a LIB= setting?

Comment: Where would I find that?  It isn't on the link line.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether one of your dependent libs that you haven't rebuilt was built as a single threaded library.

Comment: It turns out the recursive call in the makefile was the issue.  It was actually linking the library with object files from an older directory (because that was the default) and the directory override was not being passed into the recursive call.  Thus, I was probably trying to link vs 2003 single threaded code with 2019 mutli-threaded code.